# qr-algorithm to find eigenvalues not returning expected values

Tags: eigenvalues, qr

I tried to compute eigen values with the [QR-algorithm found here](http://madrury.github.io/jekyll/update/statistics/2017/10/04/qr-algorithm.html) (there is also a [wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QR_algorithm) also)

```
import numpy as np

def qr_algorithm(A, tol=0.000001):
    Q, R = np.linalg.qr(A)
    previous = np.empty(shape=Q.shape)
    for i in range(500):
        previous[:] = Q
        X = R @ Q
        Q, R = np.linalg.qr(X)
        if np.allclose(X, np.triu(X), atol=tol): 
            break
    return Q

A = np.array([[0,1,-2],[0,1,0],[1,-1,3]])

result = qr_algorithm(A)
```

In order to compute the eigenvalues of the matrix

$A=\begin{bmatrix}0&1&-2 \\ 0&1&0\\ 1&-1&3\end{bmatrix}$

which by hand we can see are 1,1,2, however I find in the end the Q-matrix

```
array([[-1.00000000e+00, -2.75303331e-07,  3.89337518e-07],
       [ 2.75303418e-07, -1.00000000e+00,  2.24783835e-07],
       [ 3.89337456e-07,  2.24783942e-07,  1.00000000e+00]])
```

which diagonal don't correspond to the eigenvalues. What is going on here?

Comment: Can you check what happens after one iteration of the algorithm rather than 500? Are the eigenvalues preserved?

Comment: Your `break` condition is only valid if all eigenvalues are real and pairwise different. In the case of multiplicities or complex pairs of eigenvalues you get diagonal blocks that do not converge and change in every iteration. Multiplicities will likely resolve due to numerical instability, but the entries of the corresponding block will only converge very very slowly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning `Q` instead of `X`.

Comment: thanks, I am going to try this as soon as I have a grab on python